# Sorting a list of strings with day-of-week names starting with Monday in ascending order

Tags: java, list, calendar, comparator

I have a list of Strings containing Day-of-week name, start time and End time in the below format:

```
Wednesday 13:00 to 14:30
Saturday 14:20 to 18:10
Monday 09:00 to 14:25
Saturday 11:00 to 12:30
Sunday 08:00 to 14:25
```

I need this to be sorted in the following order

```
Monday 09:00 to 14:25
Wednesday 13:00 to 14:30
Saturday 11:00 to 12:30
Saturday 14:20 to 18:10
Sunday 08:00 to 14:25
```

I needed to sort this list in such a way so that the Day-of-week is in ascending order starting with Monday. And if there are multiple records with the same day-of-week, then the Start time should be in ascending order too. Other examples give Sun as the first item in the sorted list but I need Mon as the first item

This is the code I have so far using Comparator class which spits out 'Sun' on top of the list:

```
public int solution(String inputStr) {
        String [] timeArray = inputStr.split(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        //List<String> list = inputStr.split(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        Arrays.sort(timeArray);
        for (String str: timeArray) {
            System.out.println(str);
        }

        Comparator<String> dateComparator = new Comparator<String>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
                try{
                    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE");
                    Date d1 = format.parse(s1);
                    Date d2 = format.parse(s2);
                    if(d1.equals(d2)){
                        return s1.substring(s1.indexOf(" ") + 1).compareTo(s2.substring(s2.indexOf(" ") + 1));
                    }else{
                        Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance(new Locale("en", "UK"));
                        Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance(new Locale("en", "UK"));
                        //Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
//                      cal1.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
//                      cal1.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
                        //cal2.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);                      
                        cal1.setTime(d1);
                        cal2.setTime(d2);
                        return cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - cal2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
                    }
                }catch(ParseException pe){
                    throw new RuntimeException(pe);
                }
            }
        };
        ArrayList<String> arrList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(timeArray));
        ArrayList<Long> arrSlots = new ArrayList<Long>();
        Collections.sort(arrList, dateComparator);
        System.out.println(arrList);
```

Can anybody suggest the best way to do that?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried and what are you having trouble with? We are more likely to help those who demonstrate some effort, or we assume you want us to do your homework for you. If you have an example which almost works, I suggest modifying it to do what you want.

Comment: *Other examples give Sun as the first item in the sorted list but...* so what stops you from modifying the example to sort from Monday?

Comment: I tried that I was trying to modify is using a comparator clas for sorting and I have tried my best to amend the code to sort the list with Mon on top but failed. I have edited my question to add the code that I have so far.

Comment: @Maxim: I have written the code to achieve the same using If statements but wanted to use Comparator class instead, if possible. I have provided the code in my question above. Thx

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 0):

I’d find it worth writing an auxiliary class for this. I want to sort objects of this class rather than strings. I can always convert back to strings after sorting.

```
public class WeeklySlot implements Comparable<WeeklySlot> {
    private static DateTimeFormatter dowFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE", Locale.UK);
    private static Comparator<WeeklySlot> comp = Comparator.comparing(WeeklySlot::getDay)
            .thenComparing(WeeklySlot::getStart)
            .thenComparing(WeeklySlot::getEnd);

    private String original;
    private DayOfWeek day;
    private LocalTime start;
    private LocalTime end;

    public WeeklySlot(String input) {
        original = input;
        String[] fields = input.split("\\s+");
        if (fields.length != 4) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Requiring four space separated fields");
        }
        day = DayOfWeek.from(dowFormatter.parse(fields[0]));
        start = LocalTime.parse(fields[1]);
        if (! fields[2].equals("to")) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Missing 'to' after start time");
        }
        end = LocalTime.parse(fields[3]);
    }

    public String getOriginalString() {
        return original;
    }

    public DayOfWeek getDay() {
        return day;
    }

    public LocalTime getStart() {
        return start;
    }

    public LocalTime getEnd() {
        return end;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(WeeklySlot other) {
        return comp.compare(this, other);
    }

}
```

Now sorting is fairly easy:

```
    String inputStr = "Wednesday 13:00 to 14:30\n"
            + "Saturday 14:20 to 18:10\n"
            + "Monday 09:00 to 14:25\n"
            + "Saturday 11:00 to 12:30\n"
            + "Sunday 08:00 to 14:25";
    String[] timeArray = inputStr.split("\\R");
    String[] sortedArray = Arrays.stream(timeArray)
            .map(WeeklySlot::new)
            .sorted()
            .map(WeeklySlot::getOriginalString)
            .toArray(String[]::new);
    for (String result : sortedArray) {
        System.out.println(result);
    }
```

Output from this snippet was:

```
Monday 09:00 to 14:25
Wednesday 13:00 to 14:30
Saturday 11:00 to 12:30
Saturday 14:20 to 18:10
Sunday 08:00 to 14:25
```

The date-time classes you use, `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date` and `Calendar`, are long outdated and poorly designed, so I didn’t want to use those. They are also ill-suited for representing your data: a day of week and two times of day. By contrast `DayOfWeek` and `LocalTime` from java.time, the modern Java date and time API, match the needs exactly. A `LocalTime` is a time of day without date and without timezone or UTC offset. And the natural order of the members of the `DayOfWeek` enum starts with Monday as the international standard (ISO 8601) says.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.